# appy fancybox on dynamically created images when mouse hovers

Tags: jquery, hover, fancybox

The function CreateImage function dynamically creates a new image and is putting them into a div. how do i use fancybox  on the dynamically created images when the mouse hovers over them?

```
function createImage(source) {
    var pastedImage = new Image();
    pastedImage.onload = function () {}
    pastedImage.src = source;
    pastedImage.width = 150;
    pastedImage.height = 150;
    pastedImage.title = 'Click on the image to preview';
    pastedImage.setAttribute('class', 'dynamicPic');
    pastedImage.setAttribute('id', 'dynamicPic');

    var dynamicDiv = document.createElement('div');
    //div.innerHTML = "";
    dynamicDiv.setAttribute('class', 'dynamicDiv');
    dynamicDiv.setAttribute('id', 'dynamicDiv');
    dynamicDiv.appendChild(pastedImage);
    $('#editableDiv').before(dynamicDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your function will generate an html like

```
<div id="dynamicDiv" class="dynamicDiv">
    <img id="dynamicPic" class="dynamicPic" width="150" hight="150" title="Click on the image to preview" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

... or ideally, your dynamic division `#dynamicDiv` should be appended to a wrapper container (unless you append it directly to the `body`) like :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dynamicDiv" class="dynamicDiv">
        <img id="dynamicPic" class="dynamicPic" width="150" hight="150" title="Click on the image to preview" src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If that is correct, then I would use the `.on()` method in its *delegated* form using the wrapper container selector like :

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".dynamicPic", function () {
    $.fancybox(this.src, {
        // API options here
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you are not using a wrapper, then use the `body` tag like `$("body")`

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LXGTZ/)**

**Note** that if you are creating more than one image, then try to assign an incremental ID to each image since IDs should be unique.

Also notice that `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

**EDIT** : if you want to trigger fancybox when mouse is over the image, then use the `mouseover` event instead of the `click` event the code like :

```
$("#wrapper").on("mouseover", ".dynamicPic", function () { ...
```

see updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LXGTZ/1/)**

**EDIT #2** : if using a jQuery version lower than v1.7 then use **[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** ... in its *delegated* form too ;)

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LXGTZ/2/)** with `mouseover` event.

**NOTE 2**: [fancybox v2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) requires jQuery v1.6 or later so the `.delegate()` option will work with [fancybox v1.3.4](http://fancybox.net/) only.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JFK 
Our application still uses 1.5.2 version of jquery, and am as evident a Jquery noob( my first task in Jquery) . Could you suggest an alternative to the "on" function that is being used.

Comment: @user2682538 : see my last edit ... just bear in mind that fancybox v2 since it requires jQuery v1.6 or later so with v1.5.2 you have to stick to fancybox v1.3.4

Comment: how each dynamically created images title can also be shown in the fancybox?

Comment: @mimocodes : the script that creates the image it also needs to create the `title` attribute for the `<img>` tag like `pastedImage.setAttribute('title', 'test title');` then just add the option `title: this.title` to the fancybox script : http://jsfiddle.net/pYm3L/

Comment: thanks a ton. learning and loving Javascript and Jquery !! :)

Comment: Hi, Is there any way in which the title of each image in the dynamic div be displayed on top of the dynamically created images?

Comment: @mimocodes : do you mean, the title in fancybox? if so check http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/